# Google JavaScript Spreadsheet property JSON from variable

Tags: javascript, json

In Google Sheets using the Coinmarketcap.com API I am trying to download data.
For this purpose, I have a loop in which I want to iterate subsequent names from the previously created table.

```js
  var listaCrypto = "BTC,ETH,ADA";
  var tabCrypto = listaCrypto.split(",");
  

for (var i = 1; tabCrypto[i]; i++) {
  
    var url='https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol='+tabCrypto[i];
    var result= UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
    
    var txt= result.getContentText();
    var d=JSON.parse(txt); 
  
    lista1.getRange(start_row + rankBTC, 1).setValue(d.data.tabCrypto[i].name);  //<-- this doesn't
    lista1.getRange(start_row + rankBTC, 2).setValue(d.data.BTC.name);  //<-- this line works
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this syntax `object["property_name"]` to retrieve a property `property_name` from `object`

```js
  var listaCrypto = "BTC,ETH,ADA";
  var tabCrypto = listaCrypto.split(",");


for (var i = 0; i<tabCrypto.length; i++) {
    var symbol = tabCrypto[i];
    var url='https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol='+tabCrypto[i];
    var result= UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);

    var txt= result.getContentText();
    var d=JSON.parse(txt); 

    lista1.getRange(start_row + rankBTC, 1).setValue(d.data[symbol].name);  //<-- this doesn't
    lista1.getRange(start_row + rankBTC, 2).setValue(d.data.BTC.name);  //<-- this line works
}
```

Comment: Google spreadsheets probably don't allow this syntax: 
"d.data[tabCrypto[i]].name" - 

SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: if that still doesn't work, try: `lista1.getRange(start_row + rankBTC, 1).setValue(eval("d.data."+tabCrypto[i]+".name"));`

Comment: Just realized your for loop doesn't cover all the values in the array.  So there's that too.  Updated